# I use jquery in github pages which use jekyll to generate website

Tags: jekyll

I want implement a function , when I move to the link, before the link will appear a picture which import from bootstrap.

---

html code like this

`<a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-link' style="display: none"></span>{{ post.title }}</a>`

and use jquery code like this

```
<script>
    $('a.post-link').hover(
        function (){
            $('.glyphicon.glyphicon-link').show();
        }
        function (){
            $('.glyphicon.glyphicon-link').hide();
        }
    )
</script>
```

my page is [here](http://lgystoic.github.com) github address is in that page.

someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your link glyph appear only on hovered title you can do :

```
<script>
  $('a.post-link').hover(
      function (){
          $(this).find('.glyphicon.glyphicon-link').show();
      },
     function (){
          $(this).find('.glyphicon.glyphicon-link').hide();
     }
  );
</script>
```